# Filter multiple columns on views using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using PowerBI for a forecasting report. One of the things i need is to identify all areas for a point to point service. For example, metro ethernet can run from a specific area to another one. when the user filters it needs to search from Side_A and Side_B. Both Side_A and Side_B are coming from the same view.
Basically I need the Dax query to do something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where side_a = 'Ex' or side_b = 'Ex'
```

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example and expected result?

Answer (score 2):

The DAX equivalent of this query would look something like this:

```
FILTER(tbl, tbl[side_a] = "Ex" || tbl[side_b] = "Ex")
```